# Scale Matrix in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I had the following list

```
id1, column_index1, value1
id2, column_index2, value2
...
```

which I transformed to a indexed row matrix doing the following:

```scala
val data_mapped = data.map({ case (id, col, score) => (id, (col, score))})
val data_mapped_grouped = data_mapped.groupByKey
val indexed_rows = data_mapped_grouped.map({ case (id, vals) => IndexedRow(id, Vectors.sparse(nCols.value, vals.toSeq))})
val mat = new IndexedRowMatrix(indexed_rows)
```

I want to perform some preprocessing on this matrix: remove the sum of the columns from each column, standardize each column by its variance. 
I did try to use the built-in standard scaler

```
val scaler = new StandardScaler().fit(indexed_rows.map(x => x.features))
```

but this doesn't seem to be possible with IndexedRow type

thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: It's just not a member of IndexedRow type. I am not necessarily looking to use a built-in function.

Comment: I know it's not, but I'm having difficulties trying to understand what you are trying to do. Why would you be using a IndexedRow if you just need the features of it (Vector)

Comment: I am just trying to build a matrix from the (sparse) representation I have as input. Then I will perform a PCA and I need to preprocess this matrix. While it was rather easy to build the matrix using IndexedRowMatrix, it doesn't seem that easy to process it. Maybe the solution lies in building the matrix differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I understood from your question, here is what you'll need to do to perform `StandardScaler` fit on your `IndexedRow`

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{StandardScaler, StandardScalerModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRow
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val data: RDD[(Int, Int, Double)] = ???

object nCol {
  val value: Int = ???
}

val data_mapped: RDD[(Int, (Int, Double))] = 
    data.map({ case (id, col, score) => (id, (col, score)) })
val data_mapped_grouped: RDD[(Int, Iterable[(Int, Double)])] = 
    data_mapped.groupByKey

val indexed_rows: RDD[IndexedRow] = data_mapped_grouped.map { 
       case (id, vals) => 
       IndexedRow(id, Vectors.sparse(nCol.value, vals.toSeq)) 
}
```

You can get your vectors from your IndexedRow with a simple map

```
val vectors: RDD[Vector] = indexed_rows.map { case i: IndexedRow => i.vector }
```

Now that you have an RDD[Vector] you can try to fit it with your scaler.

```
val scaler: StandardScalerModel = new StandardScaler().fit(vectors)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I do the following :      

    val StandardScalerModel = new StandardScaler(withMean = true, withStd = false).fit(vectors)
    val rows_normalized = vectors.map(x => StandardScalerModel.transform(x)) 
which throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Do not support vector type class org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector
 at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScalerModel.transform(StandardScaler.scala:143)

Comment: It's working if I convert the vector to a dense vector namely:
val vectors = indexed_rows.map { case i: IndexedRow => Vectors.dense(i.vector.toArray) }