# Spark and scala, how to create matrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried create matrix in apache spark from rdd. but I failed it.

How to create matrix in spark and scala?

```
resultRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Something, Something)]
(SomethingA1, SomethingA2)
(SomethingB1, SomethingB2)

val total_int_len = 10
val collectMatrix = new ArrayBuffer[Array[Double]]()
val createMatrixRDD = resultRDD.map{ x =>
    for(i <- 0 to total_int_len - 1) {
        val collectRow = ArrayBuffer[Double]()
        for(j <- 0 to total_int_len - 1) {
            collectRow = 1.1
            //collectRow += getSomethingDoubleValue(x(i), x(j))
        }
        collectMatrix += collectRow.toArray
    }
}
```

collectMatrix is empty. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342806/scale-matrix-in-scala-spark ?

Comment: Code is not executed since it is lazy evaluated.  It should probably be marked as duplicate

Comment: On a side note, this example code is really out of line with the mindset one should have when developping with spark.  For starter, the side effect on collectMatrix outside resultRDD is broken by design.